# R lubridate - error with using apply and minute

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a function that is working with `period` objects in the `lubridate` package. Specifically, I'm getting errors using the `minute()` function while using minute inside apply-ie: `apply(data, 2, minute)`.

The function that I've written is a wrapper to use `mean, sd, etc` with period objects after converting them to a numeric (count of seconds). Here's the code:

```
conv_ms <- function(x, func= "mean", na.rm=TRUE, ...) {
  # extract min/sec, convert to numeric
  m <- minute(x)
  s <- second(x)
  mns <- m * 60 + s
  # apply wrapper
  if (func == "mean") {
    x2 <- mean(mns, na.rm= na.rm)
  } else if (func == "sd") {
    x2 <- sd(mns, na.rm= na.rm)
  } else if (func == "median") {
    x2 <- median(mns, na.rm= na.rm) 
  } else if (func == "quantile") {
    x2 <- quantile(mns, na.rm= na.rm, ...)
  } else if (func == "min") {
    x2 <- min(mns, na.rm= na.rm)
  } else if (func == "max") {
    x2 <- max(mns, na.rm= na.rm)
  }
  m2 <- trunc(x2 / 60)
  s2 <- round((x2 - trunc(x2 / 60)) * 60, 0)
  return(ms(paste(as.character(m2), as.character(s2), sep=":")))
}
```

And execution. When I execute the function, I get an error using `minute()`. But But `minute` runs properly when outside the `apply` framework.

```
# run above function -- error message and traceback
conv_ms(men_g[, c(10:11)], na.rm=T)
Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz = tz(x)) : 
  do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt” 
5 stop(gettextf("do not know how to convert '%s' to class %s", 
    deparse(substitute(x)), dQuote("POSIXlt")), domain = NA) 
4 as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz = tz(x)) 
3 as.POSIXlt(x, tz = tz(x)) 
2 minute.default(x) 
1 conv_ms(men_g[, c(10:11)], na.rm = T) 

# isolate the error -- show error message
# appears to not work within apply
apply(men_g[, c(10:11)], 2, minute)
Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(x, tz = tz(x)) : 'origin' must be supplied

# but minute works on an isolated vector
minute(men_g[, 10])
 [1] 20 20 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 20 21 21 21 20 21 21 20 21 21 21 21 21
[35] 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 22 22
```

**Data** -- edited to use dput

```
dput(men_g[,10:11])
structure(list(ev6_raw = structure(c(29, 53, 27, 14, 6, 34, 51, 
6, 18, 15, 5, 4, 7, 34, 11, 51, 58, 19, 39, 8, 30, 56, 14, 37, 
9, 24, 46, 28, 51, 39, 25, 51, 40, 50, 45, 36, 52, 18, 46, 40, 
36, 16, 42), year = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), day = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), hour = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), minute = c(20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 20, 21, 21, 21, 20, 21, 21, 
20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22), class = structure("Period", package = "lubridate")), 
    ev7_raw = structure(c(44, 52, 38, 3, 55, 46, 7, 54, 6, 5, 
    12, 22, 0, 56, 23, 56, 45, 6, 24, 1, 5, 10, 24, 10, 27, 31, 
    33, 57, 19, 43, 4, 4, 11, 10, 53, 13, 10, 22, 21, 6, 58, 
    52, 51), year = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), day = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), hour = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), minute = c(1, 1, 1, 
    2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
    2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
    1, 2), class = structure("Period", package = "lubridate"))), .Names = c("ev6_raw", 
"ev7_raw"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 30L, 31L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 39L, 41L, 
42L, 43L, 44L, 53L, 54L, 67L, 68L, 70L, 72L, 82L, 83L, 165L))
```

Comment: Instead of pasting your data output, consider using `dput` to make a reproducible example.

Comment: I did think about it. I thought it was easier to work with this way. No? Happy to change it. I can also put the data on GitHub.

Comment: @Thomas - edited to use `dput`